# How could I read in a txt file in c using scanf

Tags: c, scanf, stdin

So I have to read in a txt file from the command line using '<' operator.

For example my executable in terminal would be :
 .\file book1.csv output.csv < find.txt
Where book1.csv is my argv[1] where I insert data using fscanf, output.csv is where I write the file according to my program and find.txt is where I take in arguments from a txt file in order to look for it from the book1.csv.

I am only allowed to use scanf as I have to read it in from the command line argument .

This is my code to read in the txt file inside the main function but for some reason it runs into an infinite loop printing out some sort of directory.

```
char key[66];
while((scanf("%[^\n]s ", &key))!= EOF){
    printf("%s\n",key);
}
```

This is what the txt file consists of

James Bond
Joey
Peter

So I am expecting to print the three names out one by one using my printf statement but it prints some sort of directory in my output and its an infinite loop.

Comment: @user3121023 Hi, it prints out the three names that I am trying to achieve but before it does that it prints out a weird directory of some sort. Any idea why?

Comment: @user3121023 Yes, thank you so much. The error was that the txt file were being updated to rtf as my format was different in the system preferences. Really appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `<` in a command line you program should not read from file. That means, file stream substitute `stdin` (standard input stream) and your program reads from it as from keyboard, e.g. with `scanf`.

The problem is in usage of `scanf`: read [references](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) for details and for `%s` specifier use `key` without `&` (key is already address of memory, and taking address with `&` leads to incorrect memory usage)